# Android - how to avoid memory over load using bitmaps?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, photo

My application is using bitmaps and every time the user come to the specific activity where it shows an image the second time it stops working.

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"//Pics/"Image.jpg");
```

I have tried using things like...

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     options.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];
```

Not sure what to set it too. But this doesnt help. Once the user leaves this activity is there not a way to clear the bitmap etc? thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call [Bitmap.recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) when you are done using the Bitmap to free the memory.

Answer (score 8):

Besides using [Bitmap.recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) as suggested (which is not suitable for all situations and it's a pain in the neck to be asking: "*do I still need this bitmap?*"), I always use this technique which works really fine:

```
// 1. create a cache map
private WeakHashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> mCache;
```

As you can see, it's a hash map of [`WeakReference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)s with a [`SoftReference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) as the values.

```
//2. when you need a bitmap, ask for it:
public Bitmap get(String key){
    if( key == null ){
        return null;
    }
    if( mCache.containsKey(key) ){
        SoftReference<Bitmap> reference = mCache.get(key);
        Bitmap bitmap = reference.get();
        if( bitmap != null ){
            return bitmap;
        }
        return decodeFile(key);
    }
    // the key does not exists so it could be that the
    // file is not downloaded or decoded yet...
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), key);
    if( file.exists() ){
        return decodeFile(key);
    } else{
        throw new RuntimeException("Boooom!");
    }
}
```

This will check the cache map. If the file was already decoded, it will be returned; otherwise it will be decoded and cached.

```
//3. the decode file will look like this in your case
private Bitmap decodeFile(String key) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"//Pics/"+key);
    mCache.put(key, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
    return bitmap;
}
```

Working with soft references is nice because you shift the responsibility of removing bitmaps from memory to the OS.

Comment: After all those years, do you still use this method? If so, would you please tell why you still use SoftReference while you already have a WeakHashMap?

Answer (score 1):

Be aware. 
When we think about softreferences we think that the OS will remove the softreferenced objects from memrory before reporting an outofmemory exception.

In android this is not always true. I had to implement my own caching system for images and I can assure you softreferenced objects were not removed from memory when memory was almost full.

Finally I had to switch to hard references (the normal ones) but used android.support.v4.util.LruCache for managing the cached objects. I would call recycle on the onRemoved callback from the lru cache. Its definetely  more convenient.

Cheers.